# Laravel Progress bar for data upload

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, upload, progress-bar

I am using laravel 5.1

I want to create a progress bar based on how long the file takes to upload.

I have multiple input fields and want to upload / get a progress bar on my submit button.

What would be the best (or good) approach of doing  this.

I basically have a form and already upload some file in the database.

But I do not know how to create a upload progressbar based on this.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to use a library like this one:

https://github.com/zimt28/laravel-jquery-file-upload

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use something like Dropzone js

http://www.dropzonejs.com/

It would give you the added extra functionality of allowing you to drag and drop files into an upload area. Also allowing for multiple file uploads.